# Как из родителя получить доступ к дочерним компонентам?

Tags: reactjs

в реакте знаю как передать данные из родителя в компонент, а как получить их обратно?

`UPDATE`

если реализовывать `input` отдельными компонентами, то как получить их `props/state` из `form` ?

Comment: Собственно два способа, прокинуть функцию или refs. В указанном выше вопрсое на это отвечали уже.